# C++17 expression evaluation order and std::move

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-precedence

Whilst refactoring some code today to change raw pointers to `std::unique_ptr`, I encountered a segmentation fault due to an [*order of evaluation*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) bug.

The old code did something like the following:

```
void add(const std::string& name, Foo* f)
{
    _foo_map[name] = f;
}

void process(Foo* f)
{
    add(f->name, f);
}
```

The first, naive, refactoring of the code to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void add(const std::string& name, std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    _foo_map[name] = std::move(f);
}

void process(std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    add(f->name, std::move(f)); // segmentation-fault on f->name
}
```

The refactored code causes a segmentation fault, because the 2nd argument (`std::move(f)`) is processed first, and then the 1st argument (`f->name`) dereferences a moved-from variable, boom!

Possible fixes to this are to obtain a handle on `Foo::name` *before* moving it in the call to `add`:

```
void process(std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    const std::string& name = f->name;
    add(name, std::move(f));
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
void process(std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    Foo* fp = f.get();
    add(fp->name, std::move(f));
}
```

Both of these solutions require extra lines of code, and don't seem nearly as composable as the original (albeit UB) call to `add`.

**Questions:**

- Are either of the 2 proposed solutions above *idiomatic* C++, and if not, is there a better alternative?
- I see there are changes comingi n C++17 due to  [P0145R3 - Refining Expression Evaluation Order for
  Idiomatic C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf). Will this change any of the above solutions / prevent their pitfalls?

Comment: I would say an "idiomatic" solution would be to refactor the `add` function, or add an overload that takes a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that would just move the requirement to obtain a handle on name from `process` to `add` though right? Or does P0145R3 address this issue?

Comment: IMO it's generally a good idea to push these details as far down the stack as possible. Abstraction is one of the major parts of OO and C++ after all.

Comment: I'd change `add` to be `add(std::string name, std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)`, and then say `std::string n = f->name; add(std::move(n), std::move(f));`. Inside `add`, I'd say `_foo_map.insert_or_assign(std::move(name), std::move(f));`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't `name` still be valid? The pointer to `f` is moved, not its contents...

Comment: @Altainia after the move, the internal pointer in the unique pointer f points at `nullptr`. You're then dereferencing it when you try to get the pointed value's `name` member.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Ah yes. I was thinking one step too far down one step too soon...

Comment: What is the type of `f->name`

Comment: Your two proposed fixes don't avoid the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me these 2 proposals look bad. In either of those you are giving your `Foo` object away with the move. That means you can no longer make any assumptions about it's state after that. It could be deallocated inside the `add` function before the first argument (reference to the string or pointer to the object) is processed. Yes, it would work in the current implementation but it could break as soon as anyone touches the implementation of `add` or anything deeper in it.

The safe ways:

- Make a copy of the string and pass that as the first argument to `add`
- Refactor your `add` method that it only takes a single argument of type `Foo` and extracts `Foo::name` inside the method and doesn't take it as an argument. However you still have the same issue inside the `add` method.

In the second approach you should be able get around the evaluation order problem by first creating a new map entry (with default value) and getting a mutable reference to it and assigning the value afterwards:

```
auto& entry = _foo_map[f->name];
entry = std::move(f);
```

Not sure whether your map implementation supports getting a mutable reference to entries, but for many it should work.

If I think about it again you might also go for the "copy the name" approach. It needs to be copied anyway for the map key. If you copy it manually you can move it for the key there's no overhead.

```
std::string name = f->name;
_foo_map[std::move(name)] = std::move(f);
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments it should be possible to directly assign `_foo_map[f->name] = std::move(f)` inside the `add` function since the evaluation order is guaranteed here.

Comment: Is it really necessary to *copy the name*? `[]` and `=` are just syntactic sugar for the functions `operator[]` and `operator=`. As such the statement `map[f->name] = std::move(foo)` would be `map.operator[](f->name).operator=(std::move(foo))` correct? And in P0145R3 the order of evaluation of these several function calls is defined behaviour right?

Comment: Not a 100% sure, as I haven't thought about that transformation and the standard in detail. If it's as you say then the manual stop can be avoided. But anyhow the string will be copied sooner or later, since inside the map the new entry is stored as a key/value pair. And the key is a copy of the string if your key type is std::string.

Comment: You should still be able to do `_foo_map[f->name] = std::move(f)` because, even if `f` is turned into an r-value reference first, it won't be moved-from until there's something to be moved into, which would be a result of `_foo_map[f->name]`

Comment: That sounds correct. I guess in this situation there's also no ambiguity where the compiler could generate an intermediate value where it could move `f` to before doing the remaining stuff :)

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, although IMHO it would be beneficial to make your edit more prominent, as I would say given the proposal, and the other comment, this is the idiomatic way to add the item to the map

Answer (score 1):

You could make `add` take the `f` by reference, which avoids an unnecessary copy/move (the same copy/move which trashes `f->name`):

```
void add(const std::string& name, std::unique_ptr<Foo> && f)
{
    _foo_map[name] = std::move(f);
}

void process(std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    add(f->name, std::move(f));
}
```

The `foo_map[name]` must be evaluated before `operator=` is called on it, so even if `name` refers to something depending on `f` there is no problem.

Comment: that does not fix the problem that `add()` must not touch name after `f` has been consumed. It's already the line `add(f->name, std::move(f))` that's evil and must be fixed.

Comment: @cmaster `f` is not consumed until the call to `operator=` within `add`. `std::move` does not consume anything. And that is guaranteed to be after `name` is read , because `operator=` cannot be called until its operands have been evaluated.

Comment: The problem is, that `add()` is called with two entangled arguments: modification of one (consumption by move construction/assignment) leads to a state change in the other (reference becomes invalid). This is never good and must be avoided at all costs if you want your code to remain maintainable.

Comment: @cmaster There is no problem because consumption order is guaranteed. You can add a code comment if you like.

Comment: My argument is about maintainability only: The problem is that the entanglement is not obvious from `add()` itself. When you read that function by itself, there is absolutely no indication that it must not consume the second argument before the last use of the first argument. True, the code, as you gave it, does not contain undefined behavior. But your future self that tries to maintain this code might change the order in which the arguments are used/consumed, and then the code will have UB without your future self having done anything evil!

Comment: I'd add a comment to `add` body noting that the function is designed so that `name` might refer to the target of `f`